# Leave comment when rolling back an edit?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, rollbacks

I recently rolled back [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25986323/3) because the editor "fixed" OP's original code by adding braces around several statements of a Java `if` statement. It was the lack of braces that was causing OP's problem (a syntax error at the `else` branch). Then I left a comment on the question directed at the editor.

When we edit a question, we can add an "edit summary" that explains what was done and why. It seems to me that it would be a nice feature to be able to leave a similar kind of note tied to a rollback. The "rollback summary" (if provided) could be sent to the inbox of each editor whose edit was undone by the rollback. Leaving a note in the comment thread (as I did) seems to me to be a kind of clutter, because the comment is not relevant to the question, but to an edit that is no longer part of the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, both of what you're asking for is already possible, but both of them are *a wee bit* unintuitive...

#### Notifying an editor

You already know about this one, because you did it. Yeah, it *can* be clutter - but comments on the post allow the editor (or others) to respond if need-be, which edit summaries do not. If the clutter gets *too* bad, don't hesitate to [clean it up when you're done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments).

#### Edit summaries for rollbacks

[I documented this four years ago on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back/41954#41954):

> 1. Open up the revision history on the post you wish to roll back.
> 2. Click "edit" on the revision you wish to roll back to.
> 3. Type your reason for rolling back into the "Edit Summary" field.

Voilà, a rollback with a custom summary.

Comment: I see. Very clever. So internally there's no difference at all between a rollback and a new edit that makes the same changes as a rollback and has a summary "Rollback to Revision _n_"? So one could achieve the same effect by clicking the "Rollback" button and then (within 5 minutes, so it doesn't count as yet another edit) editing the rollback edit to modify the comments?

Comment: Well... There are some subtle differences (it's a different type in the PostHistory table, and internally it tracks the revision by GUID not index) but neither of those prevents additions to the summary (or the edit, for that matter). And no, clicking the rollback button *always* creates a new history entry, regardless of grace period. I abused this fact to demonstrate this technique on that MSE answer without waiting around for the grace period to expire.

Comment: Um, maybe my last question was a bit unclear, or I'm not understanding your point. I had in mind: click the rollback button (I know that this creates a new history entry) and _then_ click the edit button on the history entry that was just created by the rollback. Does editing a rollback revision within the grace period create yet another edit revision?

Comment: Yes, it would @Ted - you can create a rollback entry *with* a custom revision comment by editing a (non-current) revision, but you can't edit a (current) rollback revision without creating a new, normal revision.

Comment: Another thing is that rollback edit summaries show up differently in different places: the post's edit history will show "`Rollback to Revision [#]`", where "[#]" is the number of the revision rolled back to; while the edit summary in the user activity list will always show "`rolled back to a previous revision`".

Comment: The question is, why is it this obscure? Though, for clarity and to be system-friendly, it would still be better to have a Rollback with message, rather than an edit based on a previous revision.