# How do you roll back an edit?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

A user deleted a lot of code from his/her question, making it, and the answers to it make no sense. How do I rollback? I can't find the option anywhere, nor an explanation how to do it in help.

Comment: Would be nice to explain this to the OP too by adding a comment. However, rollback link is in the revision history of the post. Do you see a `edited <timestamp>` link below the post, clicking on that would show the revision history.

Comment: I looked in [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25966564/revisions), but I don't see any such links.

Comment: From [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), *"Users with sufficient reputation may elect to roll back the post to a previous version (by viewing the revision history of the post and selecting the version they would like to display)."* seems like you still don't have the rights, but I couldn't find which rep will give this :/

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah, I jumped straight to the "What is a Rollback" and assumed it didn't mention it anywhere else on the page.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Users with more than 2K reputation can rollback any post, it is part of [the full edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). The rollback option is available for these users in the edit history of the post:

[image: Screen shot of edit history, rollback highlighted (freehand circle!!!!1!!)]

Users with less than 2K reputation will only see this option in the edit history of their own posts.

The rollback link is only available on ***previous*** revisions, not the most recent revision.  You can click the link to roll the post back to that revision (so you can go back as far as you think it necessary to undo the bad edits).

Users having less than 2K reputation can flag the post for moderator attention using "Other" option and describe that the post is being incorrectly edited and requires a rollback; a moderator will then rollback the edits.

Alternatively, instead of flagging, you can also drop into chat rooms such as the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ask there, any user with 2K privilege will rollback the post for you.

### Related Post:

- [Leave comment when rolling back an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271924/leave-comment-when-rolling-back-an-edit)

Comment: Is it a legit method to copy the contents from the edit history and then suggest an edit to attempt a rollback or should I just flag the post for moderator intervention?

Comment: This answer [could be more comprehensive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417665/where-exactly-is-the-rollback-option#comment906716_417665).

Comment: Note that the link to the edit history is at the bottom of the post (e.g. "edited Jun 11, 2021 at 17:51"). The circular arrow on the left side is something else.

Answer (score 9):

If you have less than 2k reputation (and therefore don't have the [edit questions and answers privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) yet), you can always *suggest* a rollback (and optionally edit the post) from the post edit screen*.

Using the "Rev" dropdown, simply select the revision of the previous edit which you desire to roll back to, they'll all be listed in this menu:

[image: Location of rev dropdown on edit page]

Once you select a revision, the page will reload to display the content from that revision of the post. When you submit this edit, it will effectively roll the post back to the selected revision, plus any edits you've made.

[image: Warning on top right of edit suggestion page]

Make sure to leave a good edit summary explaining exactly why a rollback was necessary to reviewers, since rollbacks are an uncommon sight in the suggested edit review queue!

---

* <sub>- For the 2k+ folk, users without the edit privilege are brought to a separate page when clicking the "Edit" link under a post</sub> <sub>(`stackoverflow.com/posts/${id}/edit`)</sub><sub>. You can still access this page by opening the edit link in a new browser tab/ window.</sub>

Comment: What page/view is that that shows you the Revisions list as a dropdown menu?

Comment: @TylerH <2k users don't have access to the inline editor, and instead are taken to a new page (`stackoverflow.com/posts/(id)/edit`) where this dropdown is visible. You can do this as a >2k user if you right click the Edit button beneath a post and open it in a new window/tab. This doesn't work if there's a pending suggested edit, though (you used to be able to bully over pending suggested edits this way).

Comment: @Spevacus Ah, it's been so long since I was <2k... or maybe the feature was added after I reached 2k, who knows... anyway you can probably still bully over pending suggested edits by editing them or reject & editing them from their queue item.

Comment: While this is possible, it's preferable to have rollbacks done by >2k rep users. A >2k user rollback is literally a couple of clicks. A user with <2k doing it puts the edit, *as a normal edit*, into the suggested edit queue, which requires at least two >2k rep users to review it. Reasonably reviewing such an edit may take substantial time, depending on what's done, because you have to review the edit for any other changes which may have been made at the same time (either intentionally or unintentionally). Overall, a <2k user rolling back *substantially* increases the amount of work required.

Comment: @Spevacus I believe it is still possible to bully over a pending suggested edit (if what you mean by "bully" is to override a suggested edit). However it can lead to a rejected suggested edit so personally I don't do it often.