# How to get cleanup badge

Tags: support, badges, rollbacks

The description says `First rollback`. That's all the information in the site. Can somebody give an example about what is `Cleanup` badge, and how to get it?

Comment: Um. You get it after you have rolled back a post, the first time.

Comment: [How do you rollback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271934/4642212)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When a post is edited, you can roll it back.

You click on the "edited ... ago" link, and then you see the revision history. The edit history has a grey bar above each edit, with the comment that the editor made, and buttons for "edit", "rollback" and "link".
If you hit the "rollback", the post will revert to that particular edit. The first time you do that, you earn the Cleanup badge.

Just don't roll back merely to get a badge, of course! In due time, you'll find a post that needs to be rolled back to an earlier version. And with it, the chance to earn a shiny bronze badge.

Here's a picture to show you where the "rollback" option is:

[image: rollback link]

Comment: thnx dude, never noticed the button before, I mean it might be an easy question but this is not enough to downvote it ,right?

Comment: Apparently the downvoters thought it was unclear, not useful or not well-researched.

Comment: @chouaib: since votes on Meta are also used to express agreement/disagreement (and don't count for rep anyway), they tend to be used quite liberally. Not saying you shouldn't mind them at all, but don't take them too harshly either.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, S.L Barth thnx guys but guess I won't ask a question here again hhhhhhhh they fired me from meta (but I m getting my badge :p)

Comment: @chouaib: Next time do a search first on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+rollback

Comment: @PatrickHofman: good point, wasn't aware of that, i just wrote my question then looked at the suggested posts, it was not there so i thought it's publishable

Comment: Let me know is this works only for the first time? or if there are other badges too like other badges for doing it about specific times

Comment: @ZobiaKanwal This one can only be earned once: "_First_ rollback". In this case, "first" means that it's the first time _you_ roll a post back. It doesn't matter if the same post was rolled back by others earlier. The list of badges is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), a much longer explanation is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for).