# Should I raise a moderator flag or edit directly if I don't have enough reputation to rollback a post?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderators, rollbacks

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343885/function-and-pointers) yesterday, where the OP deleted the relevant code after he/she gets the answer. I flagged the post for moderator attention, but this morning I found that my flag has been declined:

[image]

I was a bit confused with the comment - I can find a rollback option in the revision history of *my own* edit, but not on the revision by the others, so I look around meta and finally found out that [only users with 2k reputation can rollback an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271934/how-do-you-rollback#answer-271935). So I am not convinced that my flag should be declined as the reason is not sound.

However, from the feedback I get, it appears that I am bothering the moderators with something unworthy. So I wonder whether I should raise a moderator flag for such kind of issue.

I looked around for similar issues, and most of them seem to suggest to handle this issue either by raising a moderator flag, or by editing the post directly with the content of the revision intended to get rollback to.

Regarding this problem, I would like to clarify the following points:

1. *Should I raise a moderator flag?* - Is it just a misfortune my flag got declined or should I not bother moderators with this kind of issues?
2. *Should I edit the post myself?* - Is there any difference (if any) between rolling-back an edit or editing the post with content of previous revision?
3. *Which approach is more preferable? Or are there any better alternative approaches?*

Comment: You probably know this, but noting for other readers that the meta answer you linked recommends flagging if you don't have 2k rep.

Comment: If there is an active chat room relating to one or more of the tags on the post, I find the quickest way to get a needed rollback that you can't do yourself is to notify the users in that chat room of the apparent vandalism.

Comment: I agree with AirThomas, try chat first, and only bother a moderator (via flag) if chat is empty.

Comment: I would've personally re-flagged the question with an explanation that the reason the earlier flag was declined is wrong. If *that* flag was also declined I would've then gone to Meta.

Comment: @cybermonkey In my case, the moderator rolled-back the post immediately after declining my flag, so there is no need to re-flag. I do agree with you to re-flag the issue if moderators have overlooked the previous flag though.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That's my fault. Anyone can *suggest* an edit, and I thought that extended to rolling back edits too. I should have accepted your flag when I rolled the question back to its original state. You should definitely flag these if you don't have enough reputation to do the rollback yourself yet. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I don't think I can find a more authoritative answer that yours. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with @Makoto on this one. On several occasions I've seen revisions of questions *based on the answers it receives*. This is bad practice since the reason for asking a question in the first place should had been to gain knowledge in a particular area not only for your own sake but also for others to come.

Asking a question and then answering it within the question by modifying it either by changing the contents of the question or by removing for example code to match the answer deprives everybody the opportunity of analyzing and improving the Q/A. It also makes a question practically impossible to follow as the reasons for an answer becomes unclear.

I support the idea of using the roll back function - or if you don't have the reputation required, flag it. It's up to the moderators to consider the severity of such an edit, but I'd strongly recommend that such a flag renders a rollback to honor the entire purpose of the StackExchange community - to support good questions and good answers.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's fishy.  The post was made back in July of '12, which was easily 2 and a half years ago.  There's no sense in having that question devoid of its code unless someone was actively looking for *that* code online.

Worse, it impacts the existing answers.  They're building on the code that was originally provided, which would make it really awkward for someone to read without any context.

In general, I'd say roll back edits like this.  They don't make any sense and they actively harm existing answers.  Editing it yourself makes it look like you supplanted the information and that can cause confusion in our click-happy review queues.

If I didn't have the privilege to roll it back, I would definitely raise a flag on this.  Spontaneous edits of code in this fashion indicate that there's something fishy going on.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have enough rep to perform a normal rollback, you can still perform a "ghetto rollback" yourself by editing based on a previous revision (using the <kbd>edit</kbd> link instead of <kbd>rollback</kbd> in the revision history) and simply making no further changes, just putting something like "Rollback because the previous edit [changed meaning/broke formatting/was a reply/etc]" in the edit summary.

This avoids having to bother a ♦ mod at the expense of requiring edit reviewers to do a decent job, but I think that's a fair trade. And at present, rollbacks don't concretely differ from other edits (and in particular are not tracked for penalizing anyone), so there's no real reason to try to stick strictly to the built-in method except convenience.

Comment: All things considered, I think the point was clearly expressed by Bill while he was a diamond mod: yes, these are fine to roll back if you lack the privilege to do it yourself; yes, he made an error in declining the flag.

Comment: @Makoto: None of the existing posts make any mention of this method for solving the problem. I got here via a fresh dupe and felt bad dupe-flagging with inadequate answers here.