# How can I revert an edit that was made by a user who has edit privileges while I don’t?

Tags: discussion

One of my answers was edited by a user with more than 2 000 rep. (I only have 168.) I could not find a way to contact that user to ask him about his edit, but it seems pretty misled to me.

What am I supposed to do?

I’m thinking of just editing back, but I would like to notify the editor and explain to him why I disagree with his edit.

Comment: Click on edited, select the revision you want to return to and click on edit. You'll be able to enter a comment at that point.

Comment: You can rollback the edit by going to [the post revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40829745/revisions), and if you want to notify the editor you can use `@UserNameWithNoSpaces` as a comment on the post and it'll ping them.

Comment: As author of the post you can revert any change. If you want to talk to the editor @ comments work (also no autocomplete for names).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I raise a moderator flag or edit directly if I don't have enough reputation to rollback a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280720/should-i-raise-a-moderator-flag-or-edit-directly-if-i-dont-have-enough-reputati)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Although the details and answers of that question are relevant, its formulation is too narrow; mine is broader. I wasn’t considering flagging, and I didn’t know about rolling back. So I wouldn’t consider that a duplicate.

However, I finally found other, similar enough questions, so deleting my question might be a good thing. Should I do that?