# What's the best way to notify mods of answer sabotage?

Tags: support, flags

I recently noticed a series of answers by the same user receiving what I'd call self-sabotage. That is, code was made to subtly fail or be incorrect or the entire meaning of the answer changed (e.g. "X does not include Y" -> "X includes Y" when the former was obviously the case).

In the past (possibly on a Stack Exchange where I had higher rep and more permissions) I recall seeing a "Revert edit" button on the history list.
However, I can't see that option anymore, so I have been manually reverting many of these changes. However several of them are only minor changes and Stack Exchange won't let me submit a <6 character edit suggestion.

So, what is the best way to notify a moderator (or anyone with appropriate permissions) of such activity so that they can:

1. More easily revert all the changes than I can; by submitting edit suggestions I may just be making more work for editors.
2. Temporarily suspend the user until it's determined what's going on or if it's a hacked account.

Should I just flag the answers with "Other: needs moderator attention"? Is there not some way of flagging the account itself as having suspicious/bad actions?

[Edit: Specific examples removed as per ChrisF's suggestions; the individual answers have been flagged or had suggested edits made. I'd still like to know about the missing "revert" button and when I can only make suggested edits if I'm causing more work than just flagging the answer.]

Another note: there *is* a difference between a "revert" edit and one made manually (e.g. the resultant history clearly says "Rollback to Revision 2" rather than readers having to verify the edit comment's claim that that's what the change does). This suggests to me that if you don't see a "revert" button/link (I don't), then you're better off flagging the answer instead of manually trying to revert it; at least as far as the resultant history logs are concerned.

Comment: I don't see any "sabotage", he's just cleaning up his posts.  It's Sunday.  If it gets out of hand and destroying the usefulness of your personalized front page by re-activating too many questions then you can flag a mod about it.  Five edits don't trigger that problem.

Comment: Look again (perhaps I didn't include the best links), many turn working code into wrong code or otherwise completely change the meaning of the answer.

Comment: If an edit is vandalism, irrespective of who did it, revert. And an "other"-flag is certainly appropriate. Be concise and thorough, something like: "Serial Self-vandalizing, other examples: link link link"

Comment: FYI, several of my suggested edits were rejected. Possibly my comment was unclear or the reviewer didn't bother to notice that I was only reverting the previous edit which was obviously incorrect. :(  So, note to others, if making such edits be extremely clear in the comments or keep track of which edits are rejected or …???

Comment: There's normally a "rollback" link in the light blue header in the edit history. You have to click it in the **previous** version, i.e. in the version you want to roll back **to**. But I think it requires edit privileges (2k rep), which is probably why you don't see it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thanks for letting me know the exact name and were to look; the [help page on the edit privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) doesn't specifically mention rollback but indeed has 2000 rep requirement. I suppose a separate feature request would be to allow those without permission to make a suggested rollback edit.

Comment: What a peculiar thing to do. I wonder what's wrong with this guy?

Comment: @DaveC While allowing rollbacks with reviews for <2000 rep users makes logical sense, it might be kind of cumbersome to review them. Not sure if it's worth it. In any case, a custom moderator flag is always best if there's a pattern of "bad behavior". It not only needs to be reverted for the instances that already happened, it also needs to be stopped. Moderators have the tools to handle this properly. Good job spotting it, and acting on it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Probably someone trying to exploit weaknesses in SO, to have his revenge.

Comment: In general, the answer to "What's the best way to notify mods of <anything>?" is going to be "Flag it."

Comment: Also, since you mentioned "flagging the account itself", these are somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217778/192171 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1323/192171

Comment: @DaveC: While you cannot `rollback` yet, you can still use the `edit` buttons in the revision history on the unvandalized version, change nothing in the textarea, fill out the reason and submit. Though it's probably a better idea to flag for moderator attention instead of going with these things to the review queue.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271934/how-do-you-rollback

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Flag one of their answers using the "other" option.

As there might be a lot of "other" flags pending on SO at any on time, finding a moderator in chat and alerting them to your flag (as it's a potentially urgent matter) would be acceptable.

It's best not to draw attention to a specific user's behaviour on meta as this can lead to unwanted attention to the user from everyone else.

Comment: wrt to attention, I (think) I needed to link to examples of what I was talking about; should I have included the links but just not explicitly named the user? Feel free to edit my question (or tell me what edit's you'd prefer) to remove extraneous info you feel shouldn't be there.

Comment: @DaveC - if you flagged one of the sabotaged answers with "other" explaining what had happened that they'd done the same with other answers that would be enough. All you then need to do is get a mod to see your flag ;)