# What the heck is this user doing with his question?

Tags: discussion

[Structure pointer operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557318/structure-array#33557318)

Edit History:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33557318/revisions

Part of me thinks that he is trying to deface his own question because his tutor found out he was using SO for help...

Another part of me thinks he is mistaking the question for a chatroom.

I flagged it for moderator attention, but what else can I do there?

Comment: You did right. Flagging is the way to go. Nothing much more you can and should do. If you feel strongly, comment to the OP explaining why these edits should stop.

Comment: I am more inclined towards your second point. Don't ascribe to malice what can be explained by incompetence...

Comment: @Oded I did do that, but I noticed that either you or another mod deleted my comment. I assume thats to clean up and consolidate the message that such edits are not permitted into the mod comments?

Comment: Locked before I could give the appropriate treatment - somewhat annoying since I have votes left today.

Comment: @Magisch Yes. That's why. Also, it prevents the OP from lashing out at you instead of at us.

Comment: @MartinJames you'll find something else to downvote (it's been 37 minutes, I assume you have found at least half a dozen by now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post went through several roll-backs between members of the community and the OP. This is often referred to as a [roll-back war](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/578411).

Those particular flow of events raise an automatic flag but it doesn't hurt to raise a custom flag with an explanation what is going on. So you did fine.

If you're noticing an OP changing or defacing their post the correct action is to roll back their edits. If you're not at the [editing privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271934/how-do-you-rollback#answer-271935) yet you can post in a chatroom, for example in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that have regulars that handled such cases before.

I normally leave one friendly comment to ask the OP to stop doing that but 9-out-of-10 cases this is a fruitless effort. Best is to disengage and leave it at the moderators to handle.