# What defines a roll-back war and at what point do roll backs trigger auto mod flags?

Tags: support, edits, flags, rollbacks, rollback-wars

I answered this question [An edit I made to a question's title was rolled back... Where and how can I discuss this?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317831/an-edit-i-made-to-a-questions-title-was-rolled-back-where-and-how-can-i-disc). In which there are [two roll backs now to a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35676226/revisions).

There are references to roll-back wars and automatically flagging:

> If the user engages in a rollback war [we get an automatic flag.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/3956566)

...

> Those particular flow of events [raise an automatic flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310207/3956566) but it doesn't hurt to raise a custom flag with an explanation what is going on

This [Same edit suggested by a different user after the first edit was rolled back: does it trigger an event/flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315884/same-edit-suggested-by-a-different-user-after-the-first-edit-was-rolled-back-do) has no answer.

I cannot find definitions for the following.

**1. What constitutes a roll-back war?

2. How many roll backs will trigger an automatic mod flag?**

It would be good to know, then there would be no need to create a custom mod flag if an auto flag is being raised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two rollbacks from the same user on a single post over a reasonably close period of time will automatically generate the "rollback war" flag.

Don't overthink the time criteria. It just ensures that an automatic flag [will not be generated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230734/153008) in edge cases where the same user happened to roll back an edit on a post several months before the rollback war commenced.