# Why has my proposal disappeared?

Tags: support, documentation, proposed-changes

I noticed when I made a proposal to a documentation item, I didn't see that it was rejected or approved and it just disappeared.

Since contributing something is an effort the author of any change should be notified.

Sorry that I have to say this, but if it simply disappears then I tend to contribute to the simple Q+A structure in Stack Overflow (which is very good and works well) rather than wasting my time in the documentation beta.

Furthermore as it seems, other than in Q+A, in Documentation beta changes can get rejected based on the opinion of the rejector. But what if the rejector is wrong? In this case the changes are lost (and the work of the contributor as well, who might had the right idea with his/her change).

---

**Update:**

The [related section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/115345?filter-tags=c%23) appears approved:

[image]

and the changed section appears highlighted:

[image]

There is no indication on this page that it got rejected. But if I drill down from the C#6.0 Features to [Exception filters](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/46/exception-filters#t=201612160931279423693) (i.e. if I open the web site and then navigate to it), I can't see the changes.

Comment: What was your proposal? please check your [documentation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1016343/matt?tab=documentation&sort=all) if you missed something?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar: Thank you for the hint, I can see it now [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/115345?filter-tags=c%23). The section got approved, but I still can't see my changes if I drill down from the C#6.0 Features to Exception filters (i.e. if I open the web site and then navigate to it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your change was rollbacked if you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/115384?filter-tags=c%23).

Explanation given by user:

> A change is being rolled back because: This edit doesn't make sense in
>   this context. There is nothing to mitigate (the original example is
>   perfectly fine) here. The posts point is that a `when` expression does
>   not unwind a stack. Adding the 'resolution' is confusing to readers,
>   as the entire point of a when clause is to filter what exceptions to
>   catch, rather than catching all errors

Also you can see full list of edits if you click edited on bottom right corner of the example.

**Edit**

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/revisions/24?exampleId=46) your changes are first approved and after that they are rollbacked in new version. you are in list of editors.

In above link you can see

[image]

For revision view click on edited as shown in image found at the end of any example.

[image]

Comment: I still can't see where that change got rejected - see my update in the question.

Comment: @Matt No, your change was not rejected first it approved and after not much time the new proposal was inlined in which your changes are removed because of rollback to previous version.

Comment: I cannot see that anywhere - only through the link you provided. But how can I find it? It is not obvious.

Comment: I edited my answer now go to the link again and see the whole example find the part where you write your proposed change and you can see it highlighted as red.

Comment: And another thing - what if I disagree with the opinion of the rejector? It might be he/she is wrong, what can I do?

Comment: Well if you see the person who removed your part is trusted enough to get it done without approval, so if you are confident enough you can bring this issue with another question or flag it with moderator intervention on your example because other wise it will become [rollbackwar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317844/what-defines-a-roll-back-war-and-at-what-point-do-roll-backs-trigger-auto-mod-fl/317854#317854)

Comment: Thank you, that is more clear now. Final question - how can I get into this revision view? I tried it through the dashboard but seems to be not there. There is only the proposed changes tab where I can't see it.

Comment: @Matt Click on edited on bottom right part of example and then you will see list of all the edits with username.