# Edit on top-voted answer to promote another answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I happened to come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230241/5532169) and noticed that the "check another answer" part is not authored by the original author, but through [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3230241/5) that does almost nothing but promote another answer.

Is this kind of edit legit? IMO it should have been a comment because it is not the OP's idea, and it gives the false impression that the OP is telling people to refer to another answer. However, I'm not quite sure whether this is acceptable or not? If not, what should I do in this situation?

Comment: If this were a suggested edit, I'd probably reject it as an attempted reply. It really should be a comment under that answer, IMO.

Comment: To add to what @TheWanderer said; if they come back or they do this for others and there's a pattern, I'd flag for moderation. It's suspicious activity and that's worth the flag.

Answer (score 9):

I personally think that's not fair play.

Good catch.

That should be edited back to a rollback of revision 4.

That's not and fairness, advertising other answers on an answer, is very very rude.

Maybe the users should be temporarily suspended (maybe to harsh), but I will do a rollback.

Comment: The author didn't find any problem with it, nor were the readers by the stream of upvotes since that date demonstrate that the post at least wasn't worse since the edit. If someone wants to be sure, well, comment away.

Comment: _advertising other answers [...] is rude_ in this situation, when it's edited by ANOTHER user it is, but if OP does so then it's completely fine imo.

Comment: @Tas Yup, but other users (this case) is rude.

Answer (score 6):

There's a mini roll back war on it. I've rolled it back to the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3230241/4) before there were links [added](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3230241/5) to another answer and a blog post.

If this edit was made by  the answerer, no problem. It's a little unusual for editors to edit in references to people's answers on Stack Overflow.

The other answer is also sitting under the question for people to view. So linking to it is a little redundant. Links to external resources often die, so overall the edit is not especially useful, although it appears to have been made in good faith.

The post has been temporarily locked to stop more edits. If the edit is rolled back when the lock expires, roll it back or raise a mod flag. Being mindful not to start a [roll back war](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317844/what-defines-a-roll-back-war-and-at-what-point-do-roll-backs-trigger-auto-mod-fl).

Comment: Thanks for locking, so users can't edit, didn't know you can lock answers too :-)