# When the author changes the goal of the question

Tags: discussion, questions

I've answered this question last week:

> - [Subclassing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53540237/8133067)
> - [Timeline for Subclassing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53540237/timeline)

Where the author asked how to sublass `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item`. I've made a research and I've ended up discovering that this class cannot be subclassed, and my final answer was that.

At the beginning the author accepted my answer, and I [told him](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53540237/#comment93959331_53540237) that he could use extension methods to achieve what he wanted. Sometime after that he removed the acceptance of my answer.

Today I saw that he updated the question to put what he was trying to do (after discovering that the subclass wouldn't be a possibility), and then he posted an answer himself and accepted it.

So I posted this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53540237/#comment94138435_53614255):

> This response doesn't answer the original question: **How can I subclass `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item`?** The answer to the original question is: **You can't**. You ended up changing the goal of the question (based on my answer?). When this happens (another question arises, based on the answers), you should create another question, since it's... another question.

I just want to know:
Is it OK what the author did, and I should had just minded my own business?
or
It's not OK. And in that case, what is the right thing to do? Flag the answer as 'not an answer'?

Because it seems to me that this line of events turns the question, and answers, into a bunch of confusion, that can be messy for the ones that will come to the question in the future.

Comment: OP just chameleoned you with a follow up. A rollback is the best thing to do.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to rollback an edit... So, the term is chameleon question... Thanks! Didn't know about that.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit for you

Comment: Thanks for that, @Jean-FrançoisFabre! However, it answers one aspect of the question: It is not OK, and in that case you can rollback the edit. But (and in that point my question differs from the indicated duplicate), that solution only answers the question for the users who have [at least 2k reputation points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271935/8133067), and that's like about only 0,85% of the SO users. How about the other 99,15% of the users? What should we do in that case? Should we comment, like I did, and flag the answer as 'not an answer'? Or should we bring the case to Meta?

Comment: the post you linked to is pretty good. There's also SOCVR chatroom. Low-rep users usually don't care much about moderation this comes out later. You're on the way.