# Add a text field for specifying a reason when rolling back edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, rollbacks

In [Leave comment when rolling back an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271924/5740428), the top answer suggests that you can click <kbd>Edit</kbd> for any post in the history, and then leave a reason for the edit.

This is *effectively* rolling back a post with a reason, but it's poor UX because it requires an extra page navigation, and it's not intuitive. If I hadn't dug through Meta to see if this is possible, I still wouldn't know about it.

The lack of UI support also inadvertently encourages users to never leave reasons for rollbacks because it is much easier to go through the rollback dialog than to <kbd>Edit</kbd>, scroll through the post, leave an edit summary at the bottom, and then <kbd>Save edits</kbd>.

I propose that when you roll back to some past revision, the dialog should be expanded as follows:

> ##### Are you sure you want to rollback?
>
> All changes made after this revision will be rolled back.
>
> ```
> Optional: specify a reason
> ```
>
> <kbd>Rollback</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

Where *"Optional: specify a reason"* is a text input field with a hint.

Comment: I'm also more concerned about the fact that *other users* don't leave comments when rolling back edits. Even if I have learned this niche little trick that can do it, the user base at large hasn't. I'm sure it would improve the site if users were encouraged, not discouraged (or unaware of the option) to leave comments when rolling back edits.

Comment: If you do the edit trick, it also doesn't include the fact that it's a rollback unless you manually add that, which this would solve.

Comment: @RyanM The edit trick (click Rollback but only edit summary) appends your new edit summary text to system-generated text "Rollback to Revision *N* - " on, say, the version history page, but doesn't show that prefix text (which I thus guess is just a reflection of how one clicked into the edit & not part of the summary per se) on, say, the profile revisions list page.

Comment: This is a great idea. I do rollbacks myself, and see them from others, and understanding intent (even if a rollback is wrong) is helpful.